# Confused about a very basic operation on an expression.

Tags: linear-algebra

The expression that I've come to is:
$=xyz(x-y)(y-z)(y-z)-(x-y)$
When I open last two brackets, it's: $y-z-x+y$ right? When I simplify these terms, I get $(-z-x)$ as last bracketed term Which contradicts with the answer below:

The right answer is:  $=xyz(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$

So any idea what am I missing and should improve?

Comment: What is the initial expression?

Comment: It's a determinant sum:
$=xyz(x-y)(y-z)│(y-z)-(x-y)│ $

Comment: Maybe you could show that here?